# Burninate [tpl] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

I have retagged the 4 questions that had the [tpl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpl) tag, to use [task-parallel-library](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/task-parallel-library) instead - Stack Overflow doesn't have a [tpl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpl) tag.

Burninate? Synonymize?

Comment: [tpl] no longer has questions, so it will die on its own.  It can still be synonymized, but only while it's still alive.

Comment: @Jamal Stop posting answers in comments!

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: I wasn't directly answering the question (I gave no personal preference)! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Since all the current questions have been "Jamalized" (that's "Edited"), there's nothing we can do at the moment. **Synonymize** *(damn that's hard to spell, is it even a word?)* if the tag appears again.

Comment: I haven't retagged any of these questions.  Must've been someone else.

Comment: Wait, I pulled a @Jamal here?